# Spark can't load large file?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a big csv file that i want to load so i tried pyspark, however the jupyter notebook return this error :

```
IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)
```

and this is my code :

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

#readmultiple csv with pyspark
 spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
.config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
.getOrCreate()

 df = spark.read.csv("Desktop/train/train.csv",header=True);

 Pickup_locations=df.select("pickup_datetime","Pickup_latitude",
                          "Pickup_longitude")

 print(Pickup_locations.collect())
```

Comment: How large is the file?

Comment: it have 1048576 rows i download it from kaggle [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/nyc-taxi-trip-duration/data)

Comment: Apparntly The problem is in collect(), jupyter can't show all data of the dataframe.
when i change collect() to count() i get the number of rows witch is 1458644

Comment: There is no justification to use `collect` for the unprocessed, *raw* data, the way you are using it here; if you need `collect`, then why bother with Spark in the first place??

Comment: In fact my main problem is to iterate the dataframe to get the latitude and longitude of each row and then pass it to folium map,so i m planning to do like this:

for row in df.collect():
  extract lat and lon